Use PostGIS to transform geometries rather than relying on QGIS doing it on-the-fly
We have a point table in a PostGIS database that is in 4326. We load these points into QGIS but using a variety of different crss depending on the project.
QGIS on-the-fly transforms are sufficiently fast most of the time however we apply a lot of custom symbology for which we often need the geometries to be in the crs of a specific project and not 4326, e.g. because we need units in meters.
There are a wide variety of project (or "target") crss and both the geometry and attributes are sometimes edited.
For example, in the symbology geometry generator we seem obliged to do odd things like multiple transforms like this in order to get a 5m buffer:
transform(
    make_valid(buffer(
        transform($geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:6933'),
    5, cap:='square')), 
'EPSG:6933', 'EPSG:4326')               

QGIS gets crashy and slower once we have many of these configured (e.g. each point may have several such buffers symbolised), it is also simply inefficient to transform these geometries backwards and forwards so many times.
Is there something I can configure in QGIS such that it uses PostGIS for this transform right at the beginning e.g.
SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 6933) AS geom_6933 FROM my_point_table

And then use that geometry as the layer geometry, so that QGIS itself doesn't do any transforms at all?

Do you really need to keep your data in 4326 in the database ?

Have you considered to create a view into the database? Or the "execute SQL" tools from the toolbox?

As a side note using EPSG:6933 is probably not the best choice for creating buffer (it'a an equal area projection, it distort distance)

Transforms are expensive, computationally. You should really consider storing both, once, then use  views to manifest the columns you need with each query.

Thanks good points. No we don't strictly need the db to be 4326 but it appeals as a default for geometries that are used in lots of different applications/crss. The view approach is not ideal as non-editable. I didn't know about the "execute sql" tool, will test it thank you. It will be interesting to see what the consequences are re auto-detecting relations. I'd rather not store multiple representations of the geometry because of the added complexity keeping them all in sync with triggers will introduce but it is also an option.

It seems you have multiple irreconcilable requirements (dataset that won't fit in a single projection, need to use multiple different projection, need to store unprojected, need to use projected data in symbology, need to keep a single geometry column in the table, need to edit attributes and geo). Maybe the easiest solution would be to NOT use this dataset, but to extract the region of interest, save it in a per-project table with the proper CRS, edit as you wish and merge back into the original dataset at the end (or regularly)

You could use a database view as proposed by user30184. Triggers on views allow to modify the data: CREATE TRIGGER your_view_update INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON your_view FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE ... and similar for INSERT and DELETE, if needed. See details about triggers on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html
I cannot say if it is performant enough. Consider alternative pragmatic solutions. Perhaps loading, converting and storing locally the layer in the desired CRS and syncing back single changes soon enough (similar to JGH's comment). Or perhaps have a WFS (web feature service) inbetween, returning the dataset converted in the desired CRS (I'm not advanced enough to say if this is practical).
